# Omega theme conflicts with CSS of Seven administration theme, how to resolve?

Tags: theming

Not sure exactly where my problem stems from but here goes: I am developing a site with an **Omega4 subtheme**. Something in the css rules is conflicting with the CSS for the Div: `Views-ajax-popup` and overwriting the default white back ground to none. This makes the UI visually hard to use, and while I can get by with highlighting the text, but my other site users are not so adept.

The issue is I have no idea what's causing the conflict, or where to address it. In **chrome inspector**, setting the background to white corrects what I want. The css for the body seems to be the issue, it's getting it's styles Media=screen, and I can see that the default CSS is white, but it being overwritten but again no idea from where.

So, what's causing my css conflict with the admin theme and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Drupal loads the Seven theme for admin, it doesn't load files from any other theme. Same goes vice-versa. So it's unlikely either theme can be to blame, or even involved.

There's no way to guess from here what styles are overwriting others unfortunately, you'll just need to dig further with dev tools until you find the culprit.

Methodically disabling contrib/custom modules and testing the results each time is a good idea if you can't see any where else to look in the dev tools, you can find or at least rule out a culprit that way.

You could also search the files for those modules for instances of "views-ajax-popup", maybe something you have installed is specifically targeting it through CSS or javascript.

Comment: Ok, follow up, can I more specifically target it? this seems like a really simple hack to avoid a lot of bug hunting, I just haven't been able to target the view popup directly yet in sass...

Comment: Yeah it's just a matter of [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), but like I said it can't be guessed from here - someone will need to inspect the code, find out how the unwanted style is being applied, and then formulate a more specific rule to overwrite it. Or you can whack `!important` on it if you're desperate, but I'd recommend going the better route